# Is there a Tor-Browser-Bundle for the armhf /Beaglebone Black?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Trying to bring it up on the Beaglebone Black running Debian. Loaded the bundle for debian but it fails with a code of 126 and seems to be stalled at running firefox. IceWeasel, for example, runs fine on the Beaglebone Black but I'm guessing the firefox in the bundle is a different build. Or maybe it's something else...

Answer (score 0):

Beaglebone is ARM architecture, there is no build of the browser bundle for that.

You need to install Tor and configure your browser yourself, you can get the same addons and such as the browser bundle has, to get as close to the bundle's setup as possible.

Comment: OK. Well, I had already built tor from source and configured IceWeasel but given the warnings about using anything other than the Browser Bundle ( and my lack of confidence that I could replicate the bundle's setup) I was hoping for a native version. I have a bridge and a hidden site running on the Beaglebone, maybe I'll just do my browsing elsewhere.

Comment: This is a bit of a silly suggestion, but if your Beaglebone is only for Tor browsing you might install Android with Orbot, give it superuser access, and tell it to route all traffic through Tor (if you're not comfortable dealing with iptables and what not in Debian, the Android version may be a bit more user friendly).

Comment: I don't know about the Beaglebone Black, but I know for sure that my system isn't going to tolerate the notion of building an entire firefox build -- I have 2GB of RAM and 4 x Cortex A7 1.3GHz cores.  According to the firefox build instructions, you need 8GB RAM and a 64-bit OS.  Does anyone have a cross-compilation setup they can use to build an appropriate package?